# Replicating dynamic multi-dimensional array creation of PHP

Tags: c#, php, data-structures

So, I am converting a project from PHP to C#. Got a Generic List of data as a result of a query

```
//C# code
public class TermsCommodityModel
{
    public int terms_id { get; set; }
    public int commodity_id { get; set; }
    public int custom { get; set; }
    public int calculated { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string formula { get; set; }
    public int division_id { get; set; }
}
```

I was able to populate it into `termsTable` which is a `List<TermsCommodityModel>`. Then the PHP code started looping the `termsTable`.( C# and PHP codes use same variable for easy conversion). The first line completely altered my datastructure

```
//PHP code
if (!isset($termsTable[$name]))
    $termsTable[$name] = array();
```

I thought, weird but doable. Then the second condition created another child array and it went on. Now the PHP code looks so,

```
//PHP Code
if (!isset($termsTable[$name][$t->commodity_id]))
    $termsTable[$name][$t->commodity_id] = array();
//.Omitted for brevity
//....
$year = date("Y") + 5;
for ($y = 2008; $y<= $year; $y++) {
    $termsTable[$name][$t->commodity_id][$y] = array();
    for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
        $termsTable[$name][$t->commodity_id][$y][$i] = 0;
}
```

This is the final data-structure

```
//PHP Code
$termsTable[$name]
$termsTable[$name][$t->commodity_id]
$termsTable[$name][$t->commodity_id][$y]
$termsTable[$name][$t->commodity_id][$y][$i]
```

This essentially created an array of an array of an array of an array of an object dynamically. The thing is PHP is a dynamically typed language. It doesn't need to specify a type

Which data-structure in C# could possibly do this? Cant use a `tuple` as they are hierarchical, right?

Which way to approach this? Any pointers will be extremely helpful as this is kinda important.

Comment: Worth explaining what php code is actually doing, for those who do not know php (since you didn't mark question with "php" tag - knowledge of php is not expected).

Comment: @Evk: I didnt tag it PHP because tagging two languages is frowned upon. Will add the tag. Will edit question too. Thanks

Comment: What is `termsTable`? an associative array of `TermsCommodityModel` or one instance of this represented as an array? What are `$t`, `$y`, `$i`? It's kinda hard to follow what you want to do.

Comment: @Adrian: "termsTable which is a List<TermsCommodityModel>"

Comment: I mean in PHP. It can't be a list anyway since a list does not support access by key.

Comment: @Adraian: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php *An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys*

Comment: Still unclear what are $i and $y. I can show you how to handle $termsTable[$name] and $termsTable[$name][$t->commodity_id], but without knowing what you mean by $i and $y I cannot tell how you should handle the rest two lines.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I mean. You can't use C# List as a replacement for a PHP array, they are not the same.

Comment: It would be easier if you explain what php code tries to achieve (not just what this specific php code lines mean, but the actual problem being solved), because the best solution is quite likely will not result in direct conversion of php code to C#.

Comment: @felix-b: updated code.

Comment: Still not clear. What is `$name`? Where does it come from? What is `$t`? It seems to be another instance of `TermsCommodityModel `

Comment: @Adrain: I understand. I know php array can be C# array, dictionary, list anything. I wrote a list before the loop stared. now i know i have to alter it. ok? but i dunno how

Comment: no, you can't just create a `List` and then try to use it like a `Dictionary`

Comment: @Evk: poor documentation. inherited project. must follow what php does. what more can I say.

Comment: @Adrain: I can `Dictionary<string, TermsCommodityModel>`. As I said, the data structure is altered. I got a select that returns a list first.

Comment: You still did not tell what `$name` is or where it comes from

Comment: Its the `name` in the C# model. I am baffled by this PHP code :)

Answer (score 1):

I have little knowledge in PHP, but it looks like I can follow. The code you demonstrate in your question is based on associative arrays. In .NET, associative arrays are usually implemented through `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` data structure.

You start with a flat `List<TermsCommodityModel>`, and then you can build hierarchical dictionary-based structures as follows:

```
// a flat list of TermsCommodityModel, filled with data elsewhere
List<TermsCommodityModel> list = new List<TermsCommodityModel>(); 

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>>> termsTable = list
    .GroupBy(tcm => tcm.name)
    .ToDictionary(
        tcmGroup => tcmGroup.Key,
        tcmGroup => tcmGroup.ToDictionary(
            tcm => tcm.commodity_id, 
            tcm => CreateYearMonthTable()));
```

and one more helper function:

```
static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> CreateYearMonthTable()
{
    var year = DateTime.Now.Year + 5;

    return Enumerable
        .Range(2008, year - 2008 + 1)
        .ToDictionary(
            y => y,
            y => Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToDictionary(i => i, i => 0));
}
```

the following is an example of how you access the leaf values in this data structure:

```
string name = "ABC";
int commodityId = 12345;
int year = 2010;
int month = 10;

int value = termsTable[name][commodityId][year][month];
```

**EDIT**

A better approach to solve the problem is in my second answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47593724/4544845

Comment: Thanks. Will fall back to this if the dynamic wont work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how `TermsCommodityModel` is related to php code, because it's not shown anywhere there as far as I can tell. Anyway, you can achieve syntax similar to php by (ab)using `dynamic` and `DynamicObject`. First create class like this:

```
public class DynamicDictionary : DynamicObject {
    private readonly Dictionary<object, object> _dictionary;

    public DynamicDictionary() {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<object, object>();
    }

    public override bool TryGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, out object result) {
        // this will be called when you do myDict[index] (but not myDict[index] = something)
        if (indexes.Length != 1)
            throw new Exception("Only 1-dimensional indexer is supported");
        var index = indexes[0];
        // if our internal dictionary does not contain this key
        // - add new DynamicDictionary for that key and return that
        if (_dictionary.ContainsKey(index)) {
            _dictionary.Add(index, new DynamicDictionary());
        }
        result = _dictionary[index];
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetIndex(SetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, object value) {
        // this will be called when you do myDict[index] = value
        if (indexes.Length != 1)
            throw new Exception("Only 1-dimensional indexer is supported");
        var index = indexes[0];
        // just set value
        _dictionary[index] = value;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
dynamic termsTable = new DynamicDictionary();
var name = "name";
int commodityId = 123;
var year = DateTime.Now.Year + 5;
for (int y = 2008; y <= year; y++) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
        // that's fine
        termsTable[name][commodityId][y][i] = 0;
    }
}

// let's see what we've got:
for (int y = 2008; y <= year; y++) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
        // that's fine
        Console.WriteLine(termsTable[name][commodityId][y][i]);
    }
}
```

To mirror your php code even more, change `TryGetIndex` like this:

```
public override bool TryGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, out object result) {
    // this will be called when you do myDict[index] (but not myDict[index] = something)
    if (indexes.Length != 1)
        throw new Exception("Only 1-dimensional indexer is supported");
    var index = indexes[0];
    // if our internal dictionary does not contain this key
    // return null
    if (!_dictionary.ContainsKey(index)) {
        result = null;
    }
    else {
        result = _dictionary[index];
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you need to check if such key already exists (which is a bit better to my mind):

```
dynamic termsTable = new DynamicDictionary();
var name = "name";
int commodityId = 123;
var year = DateTime.Now.Year + 5;
// need to check if such key exists
// like isset in php
if (termsTable[name] == null)
    termsTable[name] = new DynamicDictionary();
if (termsTable[name][commodityId] == null)
    termsTable[name][commodityId] = new DynamicDictionary();
for (int y = 2008; y <= year; y++) {
    if (termsTable[name][commodityId][y] == null)
        termsTable[name][commodityId][y] = new DynamicDictionary();
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
        // that's fine
        termsTable[name][commodityId][y][i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Of course type safery is thrown out of the window by doing that, but if you are fine with that - why not.

Comment: Yes but that model is not used anywhere in php code so I'm not sure how it should work. Why not use two variables - one is `List<Model>` and the other for this weird stuff with dynamic table?

Comment: That's what I was thinking. And put both into another model and ship it back to the calling function

Comment: @naveen yes seems so - just combine them together in another class and you should be fine.

Comment: and its gonna be in a `List<DynamicDictionary>`. Gonna be fun

Comment: No I meant something like `class ListWithDynamicProperies<T> { public List<T> Items{get;set;} public DynamicDictionary Properties{get;set;}}`. So separate usage of `List<Model>` and those dynamic properties.

Answer (score 1):

Although the code in my first answer reproduces the original logic written in PHP, it lacks some very important qualities. It is not self-explanatory, and it is hard to read.

Specifically, things like `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>>>` is a huge anti-pattern. No one knows what is expected to be in the keys and in the values of this monster data structure. It is too error-prone.

A much better way to factor the code would be as follows:

```
public class TermsTable 
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, IndexByCommodityId> _index;

    public TermsTable(IEnumerable<TermsCommodityModel> list)
    {
        _index = list
            .GroupBy(tcm => tcm.name)
            .ToDictionary(
                tcmGroup => tcmGroup.Key,
                tcmGroup => new IndexByCommodityId(tcmGroup));
    }

    public IndexByCommodityId this[string name] => _index[name];
}

public class IndexByCommodityId
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, IndexByYear> _index;

    public IndexByCommodityId(IEnumerable<TermsCommodityModel> list)
    {
        _index = list.ToDictionary(
            keySelector: tcm => tcm.commodity_id,
            elementSelector: tcm => new IndexByYear());
    }

    public IndexByYear this[int commodityId] => _index[commodityId];
}

public class IndexByYear
{
    private static readonly int _nowYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    private readonly Dictionary<int, IndexByMonth> _index;

    public IndexByYear()
    {
        _index = Enumerable
            .Range(2008, _nowYear - 2008 + 1)
            .ToDictionary(
                keySelector: year => year,
                elementSelector: year => new IndexByMonth());
    }

    public IndexByMonth this[int year] => _index[year];
}

public class IndexByMonth
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> _index;

    public IndexByMonth()
    {
        _index = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToDictionary(month => month, month => 0);
    }

    public int this[int month]
    {
        get => _index[month];
        set => _index[month] = value;
    }
}
```

The code that uses the new data structure would look like this:

```
// a flat list of TermsCommodityModel, filled with data elsewhere
List<TermsCommodityModel> list = new List<TermsCommodityModel>(); 

// create our hierarchical index from the above list
TermsTable aBetterTermsTable = new TermsTable(list);

string name = "ABC";
int commodityId = 12345;
int year = 2010;
int month = 10;
int value = aBetterTermsTable[name][commodityId][year][month];
```

Yes, it is much more code to write, but its worth it. It is easier to read, and less error prone. For instance, one of the benefits is IntelliSense:

[image]

Comment: @Evk because these are two different approaches and I want to emphasize why the second one is better than the first one. I'm editing the first anwer to add a reference to the second one.

Comment: Well edit does not mean "replace old stuff with new". New can be just added below old one (or above).

Comment: After thinking about that - why not indeed. Though I'd say that those ways 
are not _that_ radically different to post them as separate answers, but that's subjective.

Comment: Felix, thanks, much appreciated. Dynamic is what I think too. Cos this may happen often. Our code seems to be rigid